# Accurately averaging data over time

Tags: reporting, average, data-warehouse

I'm looking for a way to quickly obtain an accurate average inventory for reporting purposes.

---

BACKGROUND:

I'm looking for a way to determine Gross Margin Return On Investment (GMROI) for inventory items where the inventory levels are not Constantin with time (ie some items maybe out of stock then over stocked, whilst others will be constant and never out of stock)

```
GMROI = GrossProfit/AverageInvenotry
```

say over 1 year

These need to be obtained on the fly, batch processing is not an option.

---

THE PROBLEM:

Given the relational database used only has current stock levels.
I can calculate back to a historic stock say:

```
HistoricStock=CurrentStock-Purchase+Sales
```

But I really want an **average invertory** not just a single point in time.

I could calculate back a series of points then average them but I'm worried about the calculation overhead (to a lesser extent the accuracy), given I want to do this on the fly.
I could create a data warehouse and bank the data but I'm concerned about blowing out the database size (ie StockHolding Per Barcode Per Location Per Day for say 2 years)

From memory the integral of the inventory/time graph divided by the time interval would give the average inventory but how do you integrate real world data without a formula Or lots of small time strips?

---

Any Ideas or References would be appreciate

Thanks B.

Answer (score 2):

In general this seems like a good case for developing an inventory fact table, but exactly how you would implement it depends a lot on your data and source systems.

If you haven't already, I would get the [Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247); chapter 3 is about inventory data management. As you mentioned, you can create an inventory fact table and load a daily snapshot of inventory levels from the source system, then you can easily calculate whatever averages you need from the data warehouse, not from the source system.

You mentioned that you're concerned about the volume of data, although you didn't say how many rows per day you would add. But data warehouses can be designed to handle very large tables using table partitioning or similar techniques, and you could also calculate "running averages" after adding each day's data if the calculation takes a very long time for any reason.

Comment: To be honest I haven't worked out the volume of data, but the hardware in use is modest. Thanks for the tip I'll grab a copy of the book and do some reading

Comment: I've a had a read of the book your recommended, it does sound applicable to our application, but the notion of manually coding SQL for the data transitions into the warehouse tables is some what intimidating. The book seems platform agnostic, I was hoping you maybe able to point me in the direction of some tools or references to help with the warehouse setup process preferably in an Ms SQL environment. Thanks B